# Why does PCA in pyspark run out of memory?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, pca, apache-zeppelin

When I run PCA in pyspark, I run out of memory. This is pyspark 1.6.3 and teh execution environment is a zeppelin notebook. Here is an example. Let `df` be a pyspark DataFrame where 'vectors' is the desired input column (containing a SparseVector of data).

```
from pyspark.ml.feature import PCA
pca = PCA(k = 100, inputCol="vectors", outputCol = "pca").fit(df)  



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/zeppelin_pyspark-2419389767585347468.py", line 360, in <module>
    exec(code, _zcUserQueryNameSpace)
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark-client/python/pyspark/ml/pipeline.py", line 69, in fit
    return self._fit(dataset)
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark-client/python/pyspark/ml/wrapper.py", line 133, in _fit
    java_model = self._fit_java(dataset)
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark-client/python/pyspark/ml/wrapper.py", line 130, in _fit_java
    return self._java_obj.fit(dataset._jdf)
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark-client/python/lib/py4j-0.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 813, in __call__
    answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark-client/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 45, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark-client/python/lib/py4j-0.9-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 308, in get_return_value
    format(target_id, ".", name), value)
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o222.fit.
: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

But check this out:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

pandf = df.toPandas()

densevectors = [np.array(sparse.toArray()) for sparse in pandf['vectors']]
xtrain = np.vstack(densevectors)

from sklearn.decomposition import PCA as skPCA

skpca = skPCA(n_components=100).fit(xtrain)
skpca.components_.shape



(100, 41277)
```

Execution time is 14 seconds. There are no memory problems, of course, because the input dataset only has ~9000 rows of sparse vectors. In spark-defaults.conf, driver and executor memory are both set at 12g, and this is an 8 node cluster that should have 32g available per node. There is no way the entire input dataset even takes up 1 MB, not even as a .csv format.

**Why is pyspark's PCA implementation running out of memory?**